# Is there a huge performance difference between datetime type and integer type when sorting? Rails 4 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, datetime, integer

I've been using Rails for 2 years and always used `:datetime` type when creating tables, and these columns were then used for comparison and sorting, such as `:start_time` and `:end_time`, etc.

Now I'm working on a new project and I'm thinking of using an additional column to store corresponding timestamps for sorting in the future, which is `:integer` type.

Is it worth doing to increase performance? The table size will not exceed 1 million rows in the near future, though.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not doing enough search before posting this question, I found this link from other questions that seems to answer my question: http://dbscience.blogspot.com/2008/08/can-timestamp-be-slower-than-datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Sure, the internal encoding is different.  Sure, there is more CPU expended for one versus the other.  But the difference is insignificant compared to the effort of fetching and dissecting the rows.

Is the column indexed?  Will you be scanning or sorting the entire 1M rows?  Optimize at the big end of the spectrum -- minimize the number of rows you need to touch.

Or you could look at the space taken: INT is 4 bytes.  In older versions of MySQL, TIMESTAMP was 4 bytes and DATETIME was 8.  In recent versions, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME are 5 or more bytes, depending on whether fractional seconds are included.

Don't mess up your application over an optimization you might not need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with the last statement.